# asp.net-core DI - scopes and registration

Tags: asp.net-core

I'm using the core version pf asp.net the first time and have a few questions about the built in DI container - Yes I know, there are a lot of other Implementations for this task. I just want to be sure.

1. Multiple implementations of an interface

   As far as I know it is not possible to register more than one implementation of the same interface.

   True?
2. Named registration

   There is no possibility (like the @qualifier in spring (java)) to register a instance / implementation with a given name.

   True?
3. Scopes

   There is no scope that has a longer lifetime than request (except singleton)
   No view / usecase / custom scope (like in java cdi / spring orchestra).

   True?

Any answers would be appreciated
And... yes, I read the docs which are quite..... release candidate like ;-)

Answer (score 1):

You've provided a correct answer to all your questions. The good news is the two ones can be fixed using custom implementations such as autofac.
Do you've any idea about this? [How to register different registrations to services (IServicesCollection) for multiple usages of the same middlewares in asp.net core?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39929456/how-to-register-different-registrations-to-services-iservicescollection-for-mu)