# How to register different registrations to services (IServicesCollection) for multiple usages of the same middlewares in asp.net core?

Tags: asp.net-core

Let's start with an example:

I've added mvc core to asp.net core pipeline two times on different branches. See following sample codes:

```
aspNetCoreApp.Map("/1", innerAspNetCoreApp => { innerAspNetCore.UseMvc(...); })
aspNetCoreApp.Map("/2", innerAspNetCoreApp => { innerAspNetCore.UseMvc(...); })
```

And I've following services configuration:

```
services.AddMvcCore().AddJsonFormatters().AddApplicationPart(assembly1ForExample).AddControllersAsServices();
```

I'd like to have something like this too:

```
services.AddMvcCore().AddXmlFormatters().AddApplicationPart(assembly2ForExample).AddControllersAsServices();
```

I'd like to use first configuration for first branch ('/1'), and the second configuration for second branch ('/2')

Note that this is a sample only, I'm not looking for some extensibility solutions in asp.net core mvc, I'd like to find a solution in asp.net core itself.

Imaging that You've developed an middleware to write exception details to response. (I'm aware of AspNetCore.Diagnostics package, this is a sample only).

Based on branching you can write something like this:

```
aspNetCoreApp.Map("/1", innerAspNetCoreApp => { innerAspNetCore.UseBeautifulExceptionWritter(...); })
aspNetCoreApp.Map("/2", innerAspNetCoreApp => { innerAspNetCore.UseBeautifulExceptionWritter(...); })
```

Now let's imaging that we've a interface to make exception details writing extensible. For example IExceptionDetailResolver, and there is a default implementation named DefaultExceptionDetailResolver. In services configuration I'd like to register different implementations for each usages of that middleware.

In Owin pipeline, I was able to achieve this using nested containers. I created a root container for the whole application, and I created nested containers for each web api configurations.
I was able to register different implementations for asp.net web api interfaces every time I added http configuration to pipeline. For example I was able to add web api several times to owin pipeline on different branches, one time for odata, one time for asp.net web api itself normal usages, and one time for web hooks. And I was able to provided Different IAssemblyResolver implementations for each of them.

How can I achieve this in asp.net core?

Additional notes: I've managed to do this for owin pipeline on top of asp.net core pipeline, and I've no problem with manually developed asp.net core middlewares too. My main problem is with some middlewares like mvc core, identity server, signalr etc.

Comment: I don't have an answer but I think this article is perhaps relevant as it shows how to do multi-tenant dependency injection with StructureMap. the same author provides saaskit which enables middleware branching per tenant so if your /1 and /2 correspond to tenants this may help http://benfoster.io/blog/asp-net-core-dependency-injection-multi-tenant

Comment: This isn't currently supported.